# Fastreport Dlphi XE7 - internal datasets - why field list is missing in design mode

Tags: delphi-xe7, fastreport

I have reports created in FastReport 5 VCL for Delphi XE7. Report has internal embedded datasets connected to ADODB. All is located on a Data tab. 
Script (code tab) contains statements to fill Connection string for ADODB component and SQL query and open each dataset. Connection string is passed to report by global report variable. Another variable contains some ID needed to get data from queries.

In design mode on the right side where my datasets (and other variables or functions) are shown I don't have field list for each dataset. In design mode those datasets remain closed until I open preview.

Lack of that fields lists makes a little hard to add some new fields to the report if you don't know how to check what query returns.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed ConnectionString for design mode and default values for ID variable